# python constructor default argument list

Tags: python

Is the default argument list the same object for all instances?

```
    class X():
      def __init__(self,a=[]):
        self.member=a   
        print id(a)

    k=X([1,2,3])
    g=X([1,2,3])
    t=X()
    h=X()
```

The output surprises me:

```
    140072782781832
    140072782901976
    140072782816536
    140072782816536
```

As you can see, the id is different when a equals [1,2,3] but stays the same when a is empty. However, if I delete self.member, now the code looks like this:

```
    class X():
      def __init__(self,a=[]):
        print id(a)

    k=X([1,2,3])
    g=X([1,2,3])
    t=X()
    h=X()
```

The output becomes like this:

```
    140033294171528
    140033294171528
    140033294206232
    140033294206232
```

The id stay the same when a equals [1,2,3].

I am totally confused... Anyone can explain that?

Comment: Only the first half of the question is a duplicate of that one. The second half is new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, which is why you are supposed to do

```
class X():
    def __init__(self, a=None):
        self.a = [] if a is None else a
```

**Edit:**

I would point out that

```
class X():
    def __init__(self,a=[]):
        print(id(a))

k = X([1,2,3])
g = X([1,2,4])   # <- different list values
t = X()
h = X()
```

also gives

```
42678232
42678232
42680152
42680152
```

so I would expect the answer is something like "if you create a list, delete it, and create another list, the odds are good it will reuse the same allocated memory location".

Comment: I think `self.a = a or []` would do the same thing, effectively, but be more succinct. (Assuming that a list is expected, and not also something else like a number, which seems to be the case here.)

Comment: @WaleedKhan: using `a or []` has the effect of using a *different* list from `a` if `a` happens to be an empty list. If the caller wanted `a` to be a *specific* empty list, then the result might be unexpected.

Comment: Can you explain the second half of the question? Why does removing `self.member = a` change the value of `id(a)`?